# How to delete secret inside a docker service?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-swarm

So i tried to make a secret using "docker secret". The command should just like below.

```
printf "Yes" | docker secret create sec -
```

And than i tried to make a service using `redis` images.

```
docker service  create --name redis --secret sec redis:alpine
```

It works like charm when i tried to access the redis service and view the secret docker.

```
docker container exec $(docker ps --filter name=redis -q) cat /run/secrets/sec
```

But the problem is, i tried to remove the secret key from the redis without deleteing the service. I did just like below command.

```
docker container exec $(docker ps --filter name=redis -q) rm -rf /run/secrets/sec
rm: can't remove '/run/secrets/sec': Resource busy
```

So i tried to stop the service using stop command.

```
docker container stop $(sudo docker ps --filter name=redis -q)
docker container exec $(sudo docker ps --filter name=redis -q) rm /run/secrets/sec
rm: can't remove '/run/secrets/my_secret_data': Resource busy
```

But it didn't stop the service, i tried to stop the service by `docker service [COMMAND]` but i cant find any docker service stop.

I also have tried to delete the docker secret using `docker secret rm`, but this error appear.

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = secret 'sec' is in use by the following service: redis
```

How could i delete the docker secret without deleting the docker services ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the service, you have to "rm" it. Thus, the command is *docker service rm*.
You cannot just "stop" the service.
**BUT** you can **update** it, using "[docker service update --secret-rm ...](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_update/#add-or-remove-secrets)"

Once it is not linked with a service anymore, you'll be able to "rm" the secret from the swarm.